# Perl: Compare every line of a file with every other line of that file

Tags: perl, loops, io, while-loop

I am new to Perl and need to so something that sounds simple to me -- but have no idea how to do it!

I have a file full of random length strings (one on each line), and am using a modified version of the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm to estimate the expected length of the longest common subsequence for strings belonging to [ACTG]*.

In order to make such an estimate, I am supposed to compare every string in the file with every other string in the file.

I thought something like this:

```
open IN "filename";
while (my $line1 = <IN>) {
  defined (my $line2 = <IN>) or last;
  #Needleman-Wunsch comparison
  #add each comparison result to a total
}
#compute average and output to file down here
```

would work - but I am not sure that this is correct. I think that this will simply read in two lines of the file at once rather than iterate through the file in a nested fashion. Time complexity isn't really an issue, so don't be too concerned with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll either need to slurp the entire file into memory

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', "filename";
my @lines = <$fh>;

for my $i (0..$#lines) {
    for my $j (0..$#lines) {
        #Needleman-Wunsch comparison
        #add each comparison result to a total
    }
}
```

or open two file handles to the same file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Fcntl;

open my $fh1, '<', "filename";
open my $fh2, '<', "filename";

while (<$fh1>) {
    seek($fh2, 0, SEEK_SET); # Rewind fh
    while (<$fh2>) {
        #Needleman-Wunsch comparison
        #add each comparison result to a total
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. To be clear, am I asking something impossible or impractical with regard to a nested loop structure? Now that I think about it, two file handles seems like a more readable alternative. -- saw your edit -- awesome, thanks again.

Comment: If you are comparing the file with itself, wouldn't `for my $i (0..$#lines) { for my $j ($i..$#lines) { ... } }` be more efficient? No need to compare A to B as well as B to A is there?

Comment: @veryhungrymike Yes, but the OP doesn't say if we're talking about an ordered comparison here.  heck, I didn't even bother avoiding the comparison with the same line, as I don't know the story behind that algorithm.  However, if it wasn't ordered, then yes, one could cut the number of comparisons in half by changing the `$j` incrementor to start with `$i`, or by doing a `seek` to the current `tell` location of `$fh1`.

Comment: Excellent point veryhungrymike -- I'll be sure to make that modification -- although it would work either way as long as I divide by the right number when computing the average.

Comment: As for the comparison of the string with itself -- the similarity score will be determinate in these cases and is easily not counted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using and studying the code of [Algorithm::NeedlemanWunsch](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm%3a%3aNeedlemanWunsch) and [Bio::Tools::dpAlign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio%3a%3aTools%3a%3adpAlign)